# Change of coordinates in 3D

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

It's been a while since my last geometry class and I need some help in solving a very simple problem I have.

I need to implement a zoom function in 3D in a piece of software I am writing. My system of coordinates is described in terms of position by the X, Y and Z coordinates and in terms of orientation by Pitch, Head and Roll angles.

The original orientation of the system of coordinates is Pitch -90°, Head 0° and Roll 180°. The Zoom in this system will be achieved by a movement on the Z axis.

When the system changes it's orientation, I want the zoom to still be a movement on the Z axis of the original system and not on the new one.

I figured out what the steps I need to take have to be, but I don't master the mathematics behind them. Please, someone correct me if I'm wrong:

1. transform the coordinates of my second system to coordinates in the first system
2. modify the value of Z to perform the zoom action (increase /decrease Z by an amount)
3. transform the new coordinates back to coordinates in the second system

Could someone please tell me how I can achieve this and if my approach is correct.

I apologize in advance to anyone that finds this question to be too simple.

Comment: Won't your approach amount to adding/subtracting a single vector in the direction of the original Z-axis? Basically you are relocating the camera? It's been a while since I did any 3D-programming (DOS support was discontinued after win98:-/), but I recall doing a satisfactory zoom simply by declaring the distance to the plane of the screen in the Z-direction to be a variable instead of being a constant. To zoom you then modify this variable: a larger distance then gives a narrower view frustrum. This won't work for you, because the zoom effect will always be along the line of sight.

Comment: (con'd) so I don't quite understand the effect you want to have? Do you want the world "compressed" (read: distorted) in the direction of some vector? Thin or short dudes walking about? Then you should multiply the Z-coordinate of the first system by some factor. Anyway, I think that zooming usually means changes of the spatial angle covered by the viewport. At least that's how zoom lenses operate :-)

Comment: The perspective for the user doesn't change... it always looks at the system from a fixed point. The trouble is I can only manipulate the coordinates of the system and not of the camera from the user's perspective. If the system has a new orientation and I perform a translation on the Z axis, it is done on the Z axis of the system, which doesn't coincide with the Z axis of the user's perspective. That's why I believe I have to change the coordinates to make the correct translation happen.

Comment: I don't know your overall 3D-engine works, so can't tell. Don't you always need to first transfrom from world coordinates to coordinates w.r.t. the position and orientation of the camera, then do 3D-clipping w.r.t. the view frustrum, and then project the polygons to the screen?

Comment: And anyway translation $\neq$ zoom.